# VS2015 MVC5 Default template, Manage External logins bug?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, oauth, google-oauth

Kinda stuck as to how this happened but I've currently enabled Google and Facebook external login to my clean MVC5 project.

Everything works fine when you login using external login but when you try to link an account from `Manage/ManageLogins` and click on either of the 2 buttons I get this error

[image: Error Screen]

Haven't Modified any code apart from adding Google/Facebook integration following the tutorials on ASP.NET

Default code from ManageController if anyone is interested

```
    //
    // GET: /Manage/ManageLogins
    public async Task<ActionResult> ManageLogins(ManageMessageId? message)
    {
        ViewBag.StatusMessage =
            message == ManageMessageId.RemoveLoginSuccess ? "The external login was removed."
            : message == ManageMessageId.Error ? "An error has occurred."
            : "";
        var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        if (user == null)
        {
            return View("Error");
        }
        var userLogins = await UserManager.GetLoginsAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        var otherLogins = AuthenticationManager.GetExternalAuthenticationTypes().Where(auth => userLogins.All(ul => auth.AuthenticationType != ul.LoginProvider)).ToList();
        ViewBag.ShowRemoveButton = user.PasswordHash != null || userLogins.Count > 1;
        return View(new ManageLoginsViewModel
        {
            CurrentLogins = userLogins,
            OtherLogins = otherLogins
        });
    }

    //
    // POST: /Manage/LinkLogin
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult LinkLogin(string provider)
    {
        // Request a redirect to the external login provider to link a login for the current user
        return new AccountController.ChallengeResult(provider, Url.Action("LinkLoginCallback", "Manage"), User.Identity.GetUserId());
    }

    //
    // GET: /Manage/LinkLoginCallback
    public async Task<ActionResult> LinkLoginCallback()
    {
        var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync(XsrfKey, User.Identity.GetUserId());
        if (loginInfo == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("ManageLogins", new { Message = ManageMessageId.Error });
        }
        var result = await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), loginInfo.Login);
        return result.Succeeded ? RedirectToAction("ManageLogins") : RedirectToAction("ManageLogins", new { Message = ManageMessageId.Error });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

K I found out what the problem was after doing a debug, by putting a breakpoint at the last line of LinkLoginCallBack(), you can see the result error in depth. For me it was because the OAuth account I logged into was already tied to an ApplicationUser

Hope this helps anyone else who has the same problem